# Load-styles.php 404 error

Tags: errors

Recently most of the websites I have build are having issues loading `Load-styles.php` on the backend.  When I login, there is no styling, just a white screen and all the links listed.
When I inspect the page I get a message that says:

```
Load-styles.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().
```

Eventually, after clearing my cache, or opening in a private window it will open, but it's off that most of my sites are doing this.

They were all built with Underscores... not sure if that is the issue?